# Replacement IC for CD4054

Tags: level-shifting, replacement

I'm looking for replacement IC for CD4054, but I can't find any other part that would work like CD4054 in level shifting. What I would need (from CD4054 [description](http://www.ti.com/product/CD4054B/description)):

*The CD4054B may also be utilized for logic-level "up conversion" or "down conversion". For example, input-signal swings (VDD to VSS) for +5 to 0 V can be converted to output-signal swings (VDD to VEE) of +5 to -5 V. The level-shifted function on all three types permits the use of different input- and output-signal swings. The input swings from a low level of VSS to a high level of VDD while the output swings from a low level of VEE to the same high level of VDD.*

Does anyone know what can be used instead of CD4054?

**EDIT 1:**

It was suggested that this question was off-topic - why? How I can't seek recommendations for specific product, if only some product (or products) can do what is needed? Also level shifting as described above, is not some niche application that no one will ever need. Same with CMOS 4000 series.

Comment: used for what??

Comment: Why do you want to replace it? They are still available.

Comment: Why are you looking for a replacement?  The part is still available.

Comment: You specifically want a single digit static LCD driver or you want a level shifter or both?

Comment: I know that this part is still produced, but I wanted to know if there are any equivalents with functionality described in italics. As for functionality, I only need level shifter.

Comment: How fast does the level shifter need to be?

Comment: @crj11 It will be enough, if it will have characteristics similar to 4054.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to use a [CD4053](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/schs047i/schs047i.pdf) or 74HC4053 for lower voltages. Connect /A to one desired output voltage source and A to the alternate one and take your output from a. But you only get one translator per package.

For example, with 0/+5V control input you can make the output +5/-5 or -5/+5 (assuming +5/0/-5 supplies).

Comment: Looks like these two that you mention are what I was looking for. Unless there are other so common IC, that perform described functions.

Comment: There are many analog switch ICs that can do this, but the 4053 is dirt cheap and okay if your needs (voltage limits/resistance especially) are modest.